# Tensorflow Datasets: Crop/Resize images per batch after dataset.batch()

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

Is it possible to Crop/Resize images per batch ?

I'm using Tensorflow dataset API as below:

```
dataset = dataset.shuffle().repeat().batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=True)
```

I want, within the batch all the images should have the same size. However across the batches it can have different sizes.

For example, 1st batch has all the images of shape (batch_size, 300, 300, 3). Next batch can have images of shape (batch_size, 224, 224, 3). Another batch can have images of shape (batch_size, 400, 400, 3).

Basically I want to have dynamically shaped batches, however all the images within the batch have static shapes.

If we do as follow:

```
dataset = dataset.shuffle().repeat().batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=True).map(lambda x, y: map_fn(x, y))
```

Does the above .map() applies to each batch separately or over the entire dataset ?

If above .map() doesn't apply to each batch separately, how can we do this ? Can we define any iterator after dataset.batch(), apply tf.image.crop_and_resize() over each image per batch and later use dataset.concatenate() to combine all transformed batches ?

I'm creating the dataset as below:

```
# Dataset creation (read image data from files of COCO dataset)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(self._file_pattern, shuffle=False)
dataset = dataset.shard(dataset_num_shards, dataset_shard_index)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(tf.cast(256 / dataset_num_shards, tf.int64))
dataset = dataset.interleave(map_func=tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filename).prefetch(1), cycle_length=32, block_length=1, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
dataset = dataset.map(tf_example_decoder.TfExampleDecoder().decode, num_parallel_calls=64)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(64).repeat()
# Parse each image for preprocessing
dataset = dataset.map(lambda data, _: _parse_example(data), num_parallel_calls=64)
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size=batch_size, drop_remainder=True)

# Below code suggested by you to resize images to fixed shape in each batch
def resize_data(images, labels):
    tf.print('Original shape -->', tf.shape(images))
    SIZE = (300, 300)
    return tf.image.resize(images, SIZE), labels
dataset = dataset.map(resize_data)
dataset = dataset.prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)

tf.estimator.Estimator(...).train(
        input_fn=dataset,
        steps=steps,
        hooks=train_hooks)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you can try something like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

dataset1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np.random.random((32, 300, 300, 3)))
dataset2 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np.random.random((32, 224, 224, 3)))
dataset3 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np.random.random((32, 400, 400, 3)))
dataset = dataset1.concatenate(dataset2.concatenate(dataset3))
dataset = dataset.shuffle(1).repeat().batch(32, drop_remainder=True)

def resize_data(images):
  tf.print('Original shape -->', tf.shape(images))
  SIZE = (180, 180)

  return tf.image.resize(images, SIZE)

dataset = dataset.map(resize_data)

for images in dataset.take(3):
  tf.print('New shape -->', tf.shape(images))
```

```
Original shape --> [32 300 300 3]
New shape --> [32 180 180 3]
Original shape --> [32 224 224 3]
New shape --> [32 180 180 3]
Original shape --> [32 400 400 3]
New shape --> [32 180 180 3]
```

You could also use `tf.image.resize_with_crop_or_pad` if you want:

```py
def resize_data(images):
  tf.print('Original shape -->', tf.shape(images))
  SIZE = (180, 180)
  return tf.image.resize_with_crop_or_pad(images, SIZE[0], SIZE[1])

dataset = dataset.map(resize_data)

for images in dataset.take(3):
  tf.print('New shape -->', tf.shape(images))
```

Note that using `repeat()` will create an infinite dataset.

##### Update 1

If you want a random size for each batch, try something like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

dataset1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np.random.random((32, 300, 300, 3)))
dataset2 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np.random.random((32, 224, 224, 3)))
dataset3 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np.random.random((32, 400, 400, 3)))
dataset = dataset1.concatenate(dataset2.concatenate(dataset3))
dataset = dataset.batch(32, drop_remainder=True).shuffle(96)


def resize_data(images):
  batch_size = tf.shape(images)[0]
  images_resized = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32, size = 0, dynamic_size=True)
  SIZE = tf.random.uniform((2,), minval=300, maxval=500, dtype=tf.int32)
  for i in range(batch_size):
    images_resized = images_resized.write(images_resized.size(), tf.image.resize(images[i], SIZE))
  return images_resized.stack()

dataset = dataset.map(resize_data)

for images in dataset:
  tf.print('New shape -->', tf.shape(images))
```

```
New shape --> [32 392 385 3]
New shape --> [32 468 459 3]
New shape --> [32 466 461 3]
```

##### Update 2

A very flexible option that works for any batch size would look like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

dataset1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np.random.random((32, 300, 300, 3)))
dataset2 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np.random.random((32, 224, 224, 3)))
dataset3 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np.random.random((32, 400, 400, 3)))
dataset = dataset1.concatenate(dataset2.concatenate(dataset3))

def resize_and_batch(dataset, batch_size):
  final_dataset = None
  duration = len(dataset)//batch_size
  random_sizes = [tf.random.uniform((2,), minval=300, maxval=500, dtype=tf.int32) for _ in range(duration)]

  for i, size in zip(range(duration), random_sizes):
    idx = i * batch_size
    if i == 0:
      final_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([tf.image.resize(x, size) for x in dataset.take(batch_size)])
    else:
      final_dataset = final_dataset.concatenate(tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([tf.image.resize(x, size) for x in dataset.skip(idx).take(batch_size)]))
  return final_dataset

batch_size = 10
ds = resize_and_batch(dataset, batch_size)
ds = ds.batch(batch_size).shuffle(len(ds))
for images in ds:
 tf.print('New shape -->', images.shape)
```

```
New shape --> TensorShape([10, 399, 348, 3])
New shape --> TensorShape([10, 356, 329, 3])
New shape --> TensorShape([10, 473, 373, 3])
New shape --> TensorShape([10, 489, 489, 3])
New shape --> TensorShape([10, 421, 335, 3])
New shape --> TensorShape([10, 447, 455, 3])
New shape --> TensorShape([10, 355, 382, 3])
New shape --> TensorShape([10, 310, 396, 3])
New shape --> TensorShape([10, 345, 356, 3])
```

Comment: It's looks good. However it's still not working out for me.

When I try to train the model, it gives error like below:
`INVALID_ARGUMENT: Cannot add tensor to the batch: number of elements does not match. Shapes are: [tensor]: [640,426,3], [batch]: [480,640,3]`

Even though I gave SIZE = (300, 300) in tf.image.resize(images, SIZE), batch has SIZE = (480, 640). And as the next image has different SIZE = (640, 426), it failed to add it to the batch.

That means somehow it's not able to apply .map() function on each individual batch.
Any help/idea ?

Comment: Could you add the code on how you are creating your datasets to your question? I think I have a clue what the problem might be.

Comment: I've updated the question with how I'm creating the dataset. Waiting for your reply.

Comment: Updated answer-

Comment: batch_size=16. It's throwing same error with batch_size > 1.

Comment: Its hard to understand what exactly you are doing without any access to the dataset you are using and the variables you have defined somewhere else. The problem is probably that each batch does not have the images all of the same shape.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239534/discussion-between-avid-learner-and-alonetogether).